# how can I apply condition on ajax responce in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
function getProject(){
    var postData = {
        'project' : proj_id
    };

    //console.log(postData);
    var site_url = "<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: site_url + "maincontroller/project",
        data: postData, //assign the var here 
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#project").html(msg);
            getSubProject();                              
        }
    });
```

Suppose that is a function now I want to apply a condition on AJAX response and response id is `<div id="project"></div>`. If response is successful then this div is generated otherwise not. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please rephrase the question and use complete sentences.

Comment: @dsdeveloper: What will return in msg ? && Please mention how you send json_encode from php code.?

Answer (score 4):

**Replace**

```
$("#project")=.html(msg);
```

**With**

```
$("#project").html(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
success: function(msg, status){
       if (status == 200) {// ok 

       $("#project").html(msg);

            getSubProject();                             
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, when leaving code in an answer, it's normally great to include it with an explanation as to why it solves the problem.